# How to run Servlet on Github?

Tags: eclipse, servlets, github

I have dynamic web project which I have made using Eclipse IDE and working correctly on tomcat. But when I uploaded the project on Github its servlets are not loading however HTML files are working fine. 
So my question is how to run those servlets on Github?

```
<a target="_top" href="showDriveClass"><input type="button" value="Show Drives" id="bt1" title="This will show current drives in your Sytem"/></a>
<a target="_top" href="DetailPdClass"><input type="button" value="Details" id="bt3" title="Details of Your Drives"/></a>
<a target="_top" href="CompareDriveClass"><input type="button" value="Compare" id="bt2" title="Compare all drives of your system"/></a>
<a href="about.html"><input type="button" value="About" id="bt4" title="About Web Drive Detector"/></a>
<a href="help.html"><input type="button" value="help" id="bt5" title="Help Contents"/></a>
```

In this html pages are loading but first 3 servlets are not.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something Github does. It will render certain kinds of files in your repository for easier viewing, but it is not an application container.

Comment: Thnks..I just learned that github only host static projects not dynamic like jsp or servlet